# Not able to use ExternalInterface.addCallBack in Flash using JS

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm new to flash and I was trying to interact with the actionscript using javascript.

My app's .mxml code is as below:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
                creationComplete="initSelben(this)"
                xmlns:a="*"
                >

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import com.flexspy.FlexSpy;

            import Fruit;

            private var numClicks:int = 0;

            private function initSelben(app:Object):void {
                SeleniumFlexAPI.init(app);

                ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFlexFunction",myFunc);
            }

            public function myFunc(s:String):void {
                Alert.show('title is :' + s);
            }
```

and myHTML and Javascript function looks like:

```
     !--  custom Script -->
     <script language="javascript">

     function callApp() {

     var title = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;


     document.getElementById("destination").innerHTML = title;

     var AddCallbackExample =    document['selben'].myFlexFunction(title);

     document.getElementById("destination2").innerHTML = AddCallbackExample;
     }

      </script>

    <body>

    <div>
    <p id="title">My demo app</p>
    <button id="demo" onclick="callApp()">Click me</button>

    <p id="destination"></p>
     <p id="destination2"></p>
  </div>

     <noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            id="${application}" width="${width}" height="${height}"
            codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
            <param name="movie" value="${swf}.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="${bgcolor}" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <embed src="${swf}.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="${bgcolor}"
                width="${width}" height="${height}" name="${application}" align="middle"
                play="true"
                loop="false"
                quality="high"
                allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            </embed>
    </object>
    </noscript>


    </body>
```

Name of my application is "selben".

Can somebody help? Neither is ExternalInterface.call working.

Comment: At which point do you execute the callApp() in JS ? The SWF will take a while to initialize and add the callback, so if you call it right away there would be no callBack added in the SWF yet. If you do it only once it would be easier to pass the title to the swf movie via flashvars

Comment: This problem I was facing is with with Chrome browser with Firefox it is working fine, thanks.